# can't figure out why this code won't compile

Tags: errors, compiling

I can't figure out what is wrong with this code, it would be great if someone could help me out:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}

\begin{document}

\def \Alt{\mathrm{Alt}}

\begin{align*}
\Alt(\tilde{B_{n}})(u) 
   &=\left[\left(\frac{\prod_{k=1}^{n} (1-u^{2k})}{(1-u)^{n+1}\cdot\prod_{k=2}^{n}(1-u^{2k-1})}\right)\right.

\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

The error message I get is

```
"Paragraph ended before \align* was complete".
```

This is a situation where I was trying to debug a much longer set of code and I got rid of everything except the first line.

Comment: Suppress the empty line inside `align*`

Comment: Is the missing big ] on the right side on purpose?

Comment: That's just because this is part of a really long string of code with a \left[ and \right] separated by several lines and I was just trying to do it line by line to see which part was causing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use empty lines in an `align*` etc. enviroment. In the example above, there's an empty line between the only math content line and the `\end{align*}` statement. The same is true for `align`, `alignat` and `equation`, `gather` etc.

It's better to use `\DeclareMathOperator` for `\alt`, since `alt` is apparently an operator.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Alt}{alt}

\begin{document}

%\def \Alt{\mathrm{Alt}}

\begin{align*}
\Alt(\tilde{B_{n}})(u) 
   &=\left[\left(\frac{\prod_{k=1}^{n} (1-u^{2k})}{(1-u)^{n+1}\cdot\prod_{k=2}^{n}(1-u^{2k-1})}\right)\right.
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I know there is a missing `]` on the right end of the equation, but I've not corrected this.

Comment: And please: No complaints about ... it would be better if you would this ... and that... and the rules of .... It's not my job to correct anything here.